# Makefile - place .o files into a subfolder

Tags: c, makefile

I have a simple makefile:

```
run: myprogram
    ./myprog.out

myprogram: main.o otherfile.o
        gcc -o myprog.out main.o otherfile.o
    
%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $<
```

right now this puts all the .o files next to my c and h files which is annoying. I want to have a subfolder called "myObj" for example where all the .o files get dumped into, but still want it to build myprog into the root folder. Online examples for this problem are all overly complex and i'm not sure what exact lines in them are essential for me to achieve this, but they seem to all have the basic `$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c` in common. So i try:

```
OBJDIR=myObj

run: myprogram
    ./myprog.out

myprogram: main.o otherfile.o
        gcc -o myprog.out main.o otherfile.o
    
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $<
```

however this does exactly the same thing and dumps all the .o files in the root folder. How, can i get them to go in the subfolder?

Comment: You must also add the subfolders here: `myprogram: main.o otherfile.o`. Also you can `MAKEFLAGS += -Rr` at the beginning to get rid of the builtin rules, which are unexpectedly being used to compile those object files outside of that directory.

Comment: do you mean like `myprogram: out/main.o out/otherfile.o`?

Comment: More like `myprogram: $(OBJDIR)/main.o $(OBJDIR)/otherfile.o`.

Comment: with the makeflags line and the modification to the `myprogram: ...` line, it is still creating o files in the root folder the exact same way.

Comment: Hint: what do you think `gcc -c $<` does?  How does it know/decide where to put the output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you need to specify that the `.o` files are in the subdirectory in your rule that links the binary, and also your rule to compile the `.c` files needs to specify the output file (in the subdirectory).

You also have some other weird things. `run` depends on a file called `myprogram` which will never exist, and runs a command called `myprogram.out`.

Likewise, you have a rule that claims to build a file called `myprogram`, but actually builds a file called `myprogram.out`.

These will probably result in your code being recompiled (or relinked) needlessly. Each rule should build the file it claims to build. So you probably want something like this:

```makefile
OBJDIR = myObj

run:    myprogram
        ./myprogram

myprogram: $(OBJDIR)/main.o $(OBJDIR)/otherfile.o
    gcc -o $@ $^

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c | $(OBJDIR)
    gcc -c $^ -o $@

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $@
```

Comment: thanks for the simple example. the only thing i added was the SOURCES and `OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))` variables from HolyBlackCat's answer so i dont need to manually add the OBJDIR to each .o file.

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed the errors and expanded your makefile to a minimally sane variant:

```make
# Disable built-in rules.
# Group the output by target when doing parallel builds.
MAKEFLAGS += -r -Otarget

# The source files.
SOURCES := main.c otherfile.c

# The object directory.
OBJDIR := myObj

# The object files.
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))

# Create the object directory.
$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

# Create the object files.
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: % | $(OBJDIR)
    $(COMPILE.c) $< -o $@ -MMD -MP

# Set linking the program as the default target.
.DEFAULT_GOAL := myprogram
# Link the program.
myprogram: $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINK.c) $^ -o $@

# Indicate that the `run` target doesn't generate a file literally named `run`.
.PHONY: run

# Run the program.
run: myprogram
    ./myprogram

# Include the `.d` files.
-include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
```

The changes I made:

- Making sure each target is named after a file it generates (or marked `.PHONY` if it generates no file, like `run`). This ensures that up-to-date files are not rebuilt when not necessary.
- To automatically rebuild a source file when a header it includes is changed:

  - Added `-MMD -MP` to GCC flags, to generate `.d` files alongside `.o`.
  - Added `-include` to include those files.
- The `myObj` directory is created automatically if missing.
- The targets now use magic variables `$@` (output filename), `$<` (first prerequisite), `$^` (all prerequisites) instead of hardcoded filenames.
- `MAKEFLAGS` is modified to disable builtin rules and to produce sane output during parallel compilation.
- `gcc -c` is replaced with `$(COMPILE.c)`, and for linking `gcc` is replaced with `$(LINK.c)`. This lets you change the compiler and its flags with some predefined environment or Make variables (`CC` for compiler, `CFLAGS` for the flags, etc). (thanks @TobySpeight)
- Object filenames are generated automatically from the source filenames, for clarity.
- Variable assignment uses `:=` instead of `=` (a micro-optimization, to not recalculate them every time they are used).
- Object filenames include the original extension (`.c`), to avoid name conflicts between `.c` and `.cpp` files if you add the latter in the future.

Comment: The `gcc` commands would be better replaced by `$(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<` and `$(LINK.o) $^ -o $@` respectively so that they pick up the usual flags variables (such as `$(CFLAGS)`).

Comment: @TobySpeight Nice! Didn't know about it. I've used `$(LINK.c)` though, since it has a `$(LINK.cc)` conterpart for C++, implying that the former is for C, while `$(LINK.o)` seems to be language-agnostic.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a better choice here (I think the two will always be equivalent, but `$(LINK.c)` conveys the intent more clearly).